# Узнать код символа utf-8

Tags: c++, кодировка, utf-8

Возможно это очень глупый вопрос, но я что-то не нашел функцию, которая возвращает код символа UTF-8.

Я знаю что мы можем получить код ASCII следующим кодом:

```
char our_symbol = 'v';
int number;
number = (int) our_symbol;
```

Как получить код из UTF-8?

Уточнения:
Есть символ кодовую последовательность, которой мы хотим узнать.

Допустим это символ `'а'` - кириллический символ.

Если перевести его байты в десятичный код то получим `1байт - 208, 2байт - 176`

Comment: Вы имеете в виду номер Unicode? UTF8 — лишь метод кодировки символов Unicode.

Comment: @VladD нет интересует код символа в UTF-8, я понимаю что символы в этой кодировке могут быть многобайтными, поэтому и спрашиваю как узнать код символа в UTF-8

Comment: Откуда берете символы? Вам нужно один раз узнать код одного симовла или вам нужно обрабатывать байтовый поток этих символов и находить их коды?

Comment: @MaximPro: Ну, нет такого понятия «код символа в UTF8». Есть номер Unicode codepoint и есть байты, которыми этот самый codepoint кодируется в UTF8.

Comment: Опишите вашу задачу шире. Мне кажется это [Ошибка XY](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-xy)

Comment: @VladD, чем Вам кодированая последовательность UTF-8 не код символа?

Comment: @tutankhamun для начала хватит одного символа, я уже писал алгоритм перевода символов в коды на php =)

Comment: @ixSci: Ну, набор байтов не код. Семантически разные штуки. Набор байтов, например, если силой интерпретировать его как число, не даст правильную сортировку. (Но это уже по идее детали.)

Comment: @tutankhamun Я задал конкретный вопрос! Как получить код символа из UTF-8?

Comment: Вообщем если подвести детали то: 1. Как получить кодовую последовательность многобайтового символа.
2. Алгоритм для сборки этой кодовой последовательности в Unicode я знаю

Comment: Если какой-либо ответ отвечает на Ваш вопрос, хорошим тоном является его принятие. Если ни один не отвечает, значит укажите, чем не устраивают существующие ответы.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот Вам простой и рафинированный вариант:

```
std::string utf8Symbol = u8"Ф";
for(const auto& byte : utf8Symbol)
    std::cout << std::hex << (byte & 0xFF) << ' ';
std::cout << '\n';
```

Отличий от однобайтовых кодировок тут практически нет: если у Вас уже есть метод выделения отдельных символов, Вы просто берёте каждый из них и извлекаете все байты, поочерёдно.

Comment: std::string utf8Symbol = u8"Ф"; - это опечатка в конце?

Comment: @MaximPro, в смысле? Нет там опечаток.

Comment: А что это тогда значит -  u8"Ф"?

Comment: @MaximPro, это значит строковый литерал в utf-8 кодировке.

Comment: Понял, не видел такого ни разу просто =)

Comment: @MaximPro, у меня есть [статья](http://scrutator.me/post/2013/12/29/various_literals.aspx) на эту тему.

Comment: Интересно, обязательно прочту!

Comment: Хм.. Кажется, [работает](http://ideone.com/HpE2jj). Я вообще-то ожидал, что std::string приведёт всё в UTF16. Почему это не так?

Comment: @Qwertiy, потому что `std::string` вообще ничего не приводит. `std::string` это лишь немногим более, чем массив `char`. Вопреки своему имени, `std::string` не является строкой, в том смысле, что мы все привыкли.

Comment: А, дошло... Это ж не wstring, про которую я подумал... Кстати, а как бы она себя повела?

Comment: @Qwertiy, опять же, по этой теме я тоже писал [статью](http://scrutator.me/post/2014/09/02/cpp_strings_basics.aspx), — прочтите, если интересно.

Comment: @Qwertiy, в `wstring` не получилось бы положить `char*` поэтому пришлось бы преобразовывать тип, а дальше ничего бы не поменялось, но при итерации она бы съедала по 2-4 байта за раз(в зависимости от реализации).

Comment: @Qwertiy: В C++ строка, в отличие от .NET, не абстрагирует кодировку от программиста.

Answer (score 4):

http://ideone.com/5IdxoG

```
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    const char *str = u8"Я строка в UTF-8. がダウンロードできません";

    printf("%s", str);

    for (unsigned char *p=(unsigned char *)str; *p; ++p)
        printf(*p >> 6 == 2 ? " %.02X" : "\n%.02X", *p);

    return 0;
}
```

Здесь используется тот факт, что для всех байт, кроме первого, два старших бита равны 10.

Comment: Круто, но хотелось бы комментарий к коду `*p >> 6 == 2`.

Comment: @VladD, википедия: "Для остальных октетов два старших бита равны 10 (10xxxxxx)." :)

Comment: Угу, может, внести в ответ?

Comment: @VladD, добавил.

Answer (score 2):

**Ну и в дополнение UCS-2 -> UTF8 -> Коды :)**

Ведь хранить строки в коде можно по разному ... http://ideone.com/bkNiH5 :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    // широкие символы
    std::wstring wstr = L"Я строка в UCS-2. がダウンロードできません";
    // широкие символы в UTF-8
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> conv;
    std::cout << "Chr | UTF-8\n============\n";
    for(const auto &c:wstr) {
      std::string u8str = conv.to_bytes(c);        
      std::cout << u8str << "   : ";  
      for(const uint8_t &i:u8str) 
      std::cout << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << static_cast<int>(i) << ' ';
      std::cout << std::dec << '\n';  
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Нет никакой гарантии, что литерал `L""` даст UCS-2, к примеру, в gcc `sizeof(wchar_t) == 4`, поэтому, наиболее вероятная кодировка там UCS-4. Используйте `u""`, если гарантировано хотите получить UCS-2

Comment: Согласен, как решение - использовать std::u32string. Но, имхо, надо выбирать от ситуации - UTF-8 дает компактность представления, UCS-2/UCS-4 дает большую скорость обработки. Все и сразу - не в нашей жизни :)