# Как прочитать японскую букву из строки целиком, а не по частям?

Tags: utf-8, lua

**Задача**

Пользователь самостоятельно редактирует таблицу внутри скрипта, который будет заменять каждый отдельный символ строки на другой символ/сочетание символов, затем запускает скрипт и получает то что ему нужно. В задумке должно быть позволено использовать любые UTF-8 символы.

```
--[[ Lua 5.3 ]]--

str = "ABC あしひ"         --строка, которую нужно обработать

characters = {            --таблица для замены символов, слева - совпадение, справа - замена
    " ",    "_",
    "A",    "1",
    "B",    "2",
    "C",    "3",
    "あ",    "a",
    "し",    "b",
    "ひ",    "c",
}

unknown_character = "*"      --default если символ не найден в таблице



output = ""                                 --сюда будут добавляться результаты совпадений
for i = 1, string.len(str) do               --цикл чтения каждого символа строки
    local c = string.sub(str, i, i)         --получить следующий символ строки
    local replaced_flag = false             --флаг того, что символ был найден, по умолчанию false
    for j, _ in ipairs(characters) do       --цикл чтения таблицы
        if j % 2 ~=0 then                   --проверка каждой нечетной ячейки таблицы
            if c == characters[j] then      --если найдено совпадение символа из строки и символа из ячейки
                c = characters[j + 1]       --то заменить символ на содержимое четной ячейки
                replaced_flag = true        --и выставить флаг
                break                       --досрочный выход из цикла, раз совпадение найдено
            end
        end
    end
    
    if replaced_flag == true then               --если найдено совпадение
        output = output..c                      --присоединить его к общему результату
    else                                        --в противном случае
        output = output..unknown_character      --присоединить default
    end
end

print(output)          --показать итоговый результат
io.read()
```

**Ожидание**

```
123_abc
```

**Результат**

```
123_*********
```

**Проблема**

Японская буква в действительности занимает 3 символа, и в ячейке таблицы хранится сразу 3 символа. Но когда я читаю японскую букву из строки в переменную **c**, я получаю не целую букву, а 1/3 этой буквы. Это приводит к несовпадению по таблице, отсюда и 9 символов * (3 буквы по 3 символа каждая).

Подскажите, каким образом мне прочитать эту букву целиком? Я же не могу знать заранее сколько символов строки мне надо прочитать, чтобы корректно провести сравнение.

Comment: Можете определить по первому байту. Старшие биты, установленные в 1 в первом байте символа utt-8 указывают, сколько байт занимает символ. Все остальные байты символа utf-8, занимающего несколько байт начинаются с 10. / Таким образом, даже попав в середину можно выйти на начало (или пропустить до следующего целого символа (например в двоичном поиске))

Comment: Вдруг пригодится: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/595299/178988

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать что так тоже можно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В *Lua* версии 5.3 есть
[функции](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.5)
для работы с *UTF-8*:

```lua
local str = "ABC あしひDEF"
local chars = {
  [" "] = "_";
  ["A"] = "1";
  ["B"] = "2";
  ["C"] = "3";
  ["あ"] = "a";
  ["し"] = "b";
  ["ひ"] = "c";
}

local unkchar = "*"

local output = ""
for _, c in utf8.codes(str) do
  output = output .. (chars[utf8.char(c)] or unkchar)
end

print(output)
-- Output:
--   123_abc***
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, идеальное решение